# Newly created inetd service always in maintenance state in solaris 11

Tags: solaris, solaris-10, smf

Till solaris 10, below were the steps I followed to create an inetd service which worked fine for me, below are steps:

1. Open /etc/inet/inetd.conf file and add my application binary with all required arguments as line below:

   myApp_5000 stream tcp nowait root /home/jack/myApp/bin/myApp myApp -h -P /home/jack/myApp/bin
2. Open /etc/inet/services file and add a entry there also as below:

   myApp_5000     5000/tcp
3. Finally I used to execute the below command:

   > inetconv -f

This will automatically create my service and everythings works fine till Solaris 10.

But now in Solaris 11, when I perform the same exact steps first I get below error message when I execute command "inetconv -f":

The manifest being imported is from a standard location and should be imported with the  command : svcadm restart svc:/system/manifest-import

Secondly, my service gets created but does not works, as it remains in maintenance state always, see below:

> svcs | grep myApp

```
maintenance    12:35:03 svc:/network/myApp_5000/tcp:default
```

I tried disabling and enabling the service but didn't helped.
Is there anything changed in Solaris 11 with respect to this, or am I doing it in the wrong way.

OS info:

> uname -a

```
SunOS myhost 5.11 11.3 i86pc i386 i86pc
```

Comment: Is inetadm(1M) reporting what you expect?

Comment: not sure what to check in inetadm, also now in another solaris 11 server services are not even getting displayed. Should i check something in inetadm

Answer (score 0):

Do an:

## ls -ltr /var/svc/log/|tail

look inside the relevant log file for your service, and see if there are any clues...

Comment: nothing useful, now even the serive name is not getting listed